# Trying to make a basic IP recognition script in PHP

Tags: php

I want to log the IP and time of a users first visit to a page. If the user visits again, I don't want it to be logged. I have come up with the following:

```
// DB SETTINGS
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";

// GET INFO
$time = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// CHECK TABLE FOR IP
(NOT SURE HOW TO CHECK TABLE TO SEE IF IP HAS ALREADY BEEN LOGGED
If log is found I would name it $loggedip)

// IF IP EXISTS
if ($loggedip == $ip) {echo logged;} 


// WRITE NEW IP
else {

$sql = "INSERT INTO catcher (ip, id, time)
VALUES ('$ip', 'id', '$time')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


}

$conn->close();

?>
```

I cannot figure out how to check my database to see if the address as been logged already. Everything else works fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Apache does this for you in its access log

Comment: I know, but I want to generate specific pages depending on the users IP.

Comment: ok but IP != user, one IP can be hundreds of people, one person can use hundreds if IP's

Comment: I understand that. Its okay though.

Answer (score 0):

Make the IP address the primary key of your log table, or add a unique index to the IP column. This will cause the insert statement to simply fail if the IP already exists.

Then, change the insert statement as follows:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO catcher (ip, id, time)
VALUES ('$ip', 'id', '$time')"
```

The `IGNORE` clause will cause the insert statement to simply do nothing if there is an error. This way, the statement itself will appear to be successful, so you won't get an error. You may check the number of rows affected to see if a row was inserted or not.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was not clear enough though, I would like to generate a countdown timer for each IP based on the time stamp. using ignore might not be the best option here.

Comment: Why not? It does exactly do what you asked for. The main solution is adding the unique index. This simply doesn't allow you to insert the IP a second time. Adding `IGNORE` is just one of the ways to suppress any errors you might get when attempting to insert a duplicate IP.